# PostgreSql 9.3 Server doesn't listen after cluster recreate

Tags: linux, postgresql, utf-8

My postgres server has refused connection before  but I have fixed it using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432) solution.

> This issue comes from installing the postgres package with out a version number. Although postgres will be installed and it will be the correct version, the script to setup the cluster will not run correctly; it's a packaging issue...

It suggest to purge and reinstall postgres and it will be fixed. It helped me last time.

Currently my problem is related to PostgreSql UTF-8 issues and so I have to do the following to my working postgres and I cannot just purge and reinstall.

So here is what I did before I lost the connection:

- `sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main stop --force`
- `sudo pg_dropcluster –stop 9.3 main`
- `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" sudo pg_createcluster --start 9.3 main`

Now the cluster was recreated and the UTF-8 problem was supposedly fixed.

But now I cannot connect to the server.

Here is what I did to try to fix it:

- `sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.3 main start` 
  which told me
- Cluster is already running
- So I listened to the port with `netstat -nlp | grep 5432` and it told me that `680/postgres` is running on the port
- After this I tried to restart postgres by doing
- `/etc/init.d/postgresql stop/start`
- All successful but still not connecting to database through pgAdmin III on a remote desktop.

Does anyone have a clue what is the root cause here and why am i getting rejected from the connection?

Many thanks!

Comment: _it told me that 680/postgres is running on the port_: that's not sufficient. It must listen on the network interface through which your remote desktop tries to connect. See the `listen_addresses` configuration.

Comment: @DanielVérité my postgresql.conf file is all commented out with #listen_addresses = 'localhost'

Comment: So it's not listening to your ethernet interface, which means no remote  connection possible. Set `listen_addresses = '*'` and restart.